# Holoviews - network graph - change edge color

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh, holoviews

I am using `holoviews` and `bokeh` with python 3 to create an interactive network graph fro mNetworkx. I can't manage to set the edge color to blank. It seems that the `edge_color` option does not exist. Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the option to change edges color is `edge_line_color` and not `edge_color`.